# Prove that if $[x]_n\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ has order $2^a$ then there exists $p$ prime such that $p|n$ and $2^a|p-1$, for $n\geq3$ odd.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve the following computational algebra exercise:

Given an odd natural number $n\geq3$ and $x\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ an element with order $2^a$ for $a\geq 1$, prove that there exists a prime $p$ such that $p\ |\ n$ and $2^a\ |\ p-1$. ($\mathbb{Z}_n$ denotes the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ the multiplicative group of the units of $\mathbb{Z}_n$).

I've tried the following:

Expressing $n=p_1^{n_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{n_k}$ where $p_i$ are the prime factors of $n$ and using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_{q^m}^*\cong\mathbb{Z}_{\varphi(q^m)}$ for every $q\geq 3$ prime and $m\geq 1$ (I can use this result because $n$ is odd) we have

$$\mathbb{Z}_n^*\cong
\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_1}}^*\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_k}}^*\cong
\mathbb{Z}_{\varphi(p^{n_1})}\oplus\dots\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{\varphi(p^{n_k})}.
$$

The fact that there exists $x\in\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ with order $2^a$ is equivalent to $2^a\ |\ |\mathbb{Z}_n^*|$ and using Euler's Totient function

$$|\mathbb{Z}_n^*|
  =\varphi\left(n\right)
  =\varphi\left(p_1^{n_1}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot\varphi\left({p_k}^{n_k}\right)
  =p_1^{n_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{n_k-1}(p_k-1).
$$

I think I'm almost there: if I could show that the element $x$ is in one of the $\mathbb{Z}_{\varphi(p^{n_i})}$ I would have that $2^a\ |\ p_i^{n_i-1}(p_i-1) \Rightarrow 2^a\ |\ p_i-1$ because $p_i^{n_i-1}$ must be odd. This is the thing I can't figure out how to prove.

Thanks in advance for any help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Use `$p\mid n$` for $p\mid n$.

Comment: I dont see how that could help me prove that 2^a | p-1.

Comment: "The fact that there exists $x\in\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ with order $2^a$ is equivalent to $2^a\ |\ |\mathbb{Z}_n^*|$" is incorrect—try $n=8$ for example.

Comment: Hint: if $(g_1,\dots,g_k)$ is an element of $G_1\oplus\cdots\oplus G_k$ and each $g_j$ has order $m_j$ in $G_k$, prove that $(g_1,\dots,g_k)$ has order lcm$(m_1,\dots,m_k)$ in $G_1\oplus\cdots\oplus G_k$. That will help you bridge the gap between your first strategy and the end of your second strategy.